# Is there a COPY command equivalent for unselecting columns in pgAdmin whose values are meant to be default?

Tags: pgadmin, postgresql-10, postgresql-copy

Several of my tables have fields with default values, including this one:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS checks (
    shipmentid  INT             NOT NULL,
    status      VARCHAR(10)     DEFAULT 'COUNTED' NOT NULL,
    date        DATE            NOT NULL,
    time        TIME            NOT NULL,
    employeeid  INT             NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_checks PRIMARY KEY (shipmentid, status),       -- added status to the pkey, removed employeeid
    CONSTRAINT fk_checks_shipment FOREIGN KEY (shipmentid)
        REFERENCES shipment(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_checks_employee FOREIGN KEY (employeeid)
        REFERENCES employee(id)
);
```

In pgAdmin, if I use a CSV file to import mock data, I can simply uncheck the box for "status" in the Columns tab and the value of "status" for every row is 'COUNTED'. How do I do the same on the command line in PSQL? I frequently wipe the table data and reimport it to start fresh to test different things and I'd like to be able to do it with all the COPY commands in a .sql file and do something like:

```
\i C:/table_data.sql
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `copy table_name (col1, col2, col3) ....`

Comment: thank you @a_horse_with_no_name